# How to check with multiple fields and check case senstive in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have `listOfintrests = ["T-shirts","Jeans","Trousers","watches"]` which I'm searching with courses collection, but I'm getting an error

`Cast to string failed for value "{ '$regex': /^T-shirts,Jeans,Trousers,watches$/, '$options': 'i' }" (type Object) at path "category" for model "course"`

```
const isCourse = await Courses.find({ category : {$in : { $regex: new RegExp(`^${listOfintrests}$`), $options: 'i' }} });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help me thanks in advance.

this is the course collection:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need concat the array elements with regex `|` or operator

```
const isCourse = await Courses.find({ category : new RegExp(listOfintrests.join('|'), 'i') }
```